# PhoneGap app to act as a server

Tags: html, cordova, connection

I am trying to develop an HTML5 app to be ported to native via PhoneGap. Is it possible for the app to be able to act as a server on a mobile device, with the same app on another mobile device acting as a client and connecting to the former? This is all within a local network.

I am new to PhoneGap and I understand that most server implementations are on platforms such as node.js or PHP and that PhoneGap only supports HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I think I might be partially wrong here as there are various plugins that could help ease the abstraction between PhoneGap and the native developer.

Other alternative suggestions are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying do by having a client/server app? I think your best bet would be to have one app that posts and gets info to your own webserver (not an app). Therefore, that one app can act as a server by "publishing" information to the server and the other can act as a client by only reading from the server.

Comment: The app that I am trying to develop is quite similar to the iPad app Air Sketch, but using HTML canvas. While I considered using a webserver, I would prefer otherwise. Air Sketch provides an IP address and a port to be used, and is simply accessed on another web browser to view the drawings done on Air Sketch. If I'm not mistaken, it uses WebSockets or something similar. I want to know if this is possible in an HTML5 app ported to native using PhoneGap.

Comment: Yeah... That would require a plugin or two that dont exist to my knowledge. Recommend doing it via a real server. Then you can create a web front end also and let users use your app and website to access/draw/share their stuff.